# Error when creating SharePoint WebPart in Visual Studio - "An error occurred while generating the project"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint

I am getting a Error in Visual Studio when I create a SharePoint Web Part.. "An error occurred while generating the project. Please see the Visual Studio Output window for more information."

I have checked the Output window and there is noting in it. When I click OK I get the next error that states

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

After I click oky.. There seems to be files missing in the Solution Explorer..

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and SharePoint 2013 Enterprise. These run on Windows Server 2012 R2..

This mind boggling.. Hope someone can help..

Thanks

Comment: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Ended up installing VS 2012 and VS 2012 Office Tools for now and it worked strait out the box.. But still want to know whats wrong with VS 2013. Would really like to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, double check your **Features and Package** for any item added to 'items in this feature/package' but having an error

Comment: I assume you are talking about inside the solution explorer. There is noting in Features and inside Package it has Package.package and under it there is a Package.Template.xml and that is it.

Comment: double click package/feature i mean

Comment: Oky, When I Double clicked the package I got the following error.. [link](http://i1294.photobucket.com/albums/b604/matrix4404/Blog%20-%20Light%20on%20the%20situation/Error00_zpsc3312ca1.png)  And after I closed it and double clicked Again I got [link](http://i1294.photobucket.com/albums/b604/matrix4404/Blog%20-%20Light%20on%20the%20situation/Error0_zpsd3ea272c.png)

Comment: i think it's something related to visual studio update

Comment: I have updated VS.. I Found that there may be packages missing. SO I am going to reinstall for the 2nd time.